# After Created in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

In controller my code is

```
query = "insert into users (name, email,updated_at) values (#{name},#{email},now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at=now()"
```

> User.connection.execute(query)

and in model

```
after_create :change_updated_at

    def change_updated_at
     if !self.email.blank?
       chk_user = User.find_by_id(self.email)
       if !chk_user.blank? && chk_user.updated_at.blank?          
          chk_user.updated_at =Time.now
          chk_user.save!
       end
     end

end
```

but it's not working please help

Comment: be careful with this! this is a huge(!!) sql injection vulnerability. better rely on rails orm (activerecord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be replaced by something like this. This will provide the same functionality as using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
user = User.where("name = ? and email = ?", name, email)
if user.nil?
    user = User.new 
end
user.name = name
user.email = email
user.save
```

Since you want this function to run even if it is an update. You want to use the `after_save` callback http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save

The `after_create` is called only on creation of brand new objects.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create

List of all callbacks provided by active record are here 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks

Comment: Your first line needs arguments for what to put in for the ?'s.  `user = User.where("name = ? and email = ?", name, email)`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run your query directly, that's VERY un-rails like. Let rails generate the query for you.
By running it yourself, rails has no way of knowing that you've created the record, so the `after_create` filter isn't be called.

Change your code to something like :

```
User.create(name: name, email: email)
```

Then it'll run. Also, don't update the 'create_at' field yourself. If you use rails methods, it'll do this automatically for you as well :)

Comment: is it possible in my code because if i change my query then i face many problems

Comment: @RavendraKumar Look at my answer. I have tried to address this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get with params object input attributes.
So first of all you need new method, and then create method (if you use standart form helper for model):

```
def create
@user=User.new(params[:user])
#other code
end
```